# Searching for value in an array of tuples is very slow

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

Let's assume this task:

> Generate array A of big random numbers. Sort them. Then generate random number and check if such number exists in array A. Repeat. If found, return its original **position** (before sort) in the array A and the number's value.

---

**Example:** array A before sort:

```
+-------+------------------------+
| index | 0 1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8 |
| value | 1 3 9 27 81 17 51 40 7 |
+-------+------------------------+
```

After sort:

```
+-------+------------------------+
| index | 0 1 8 2 5  9  3  7  6 |
| value | 1 3 7 9 17 21 27 40 51 |
+-------+------------------------+
```

Does the number 21 exists in the array? Yes, on index 9!

---

I came up with following solution:

```
def value_exists(needle, haystack):
    # finds if needle exists in haystack of tuples and returns it if so
    for item in haystack:
        if item[1] > needle:
            return None
        if item[1] == needle:
            return item

n = 200000
size = 100000000

# fill array A with random numbers
arrayA = [1]
for i in range(1, n):
    arrayA.append(randint(0, size))
arrayA = enumerate(arrayA)
# sort them by values keeping its indexes
arrayA = sorted(arrayA, key=lambda x: x[1])

# search
for i in range(1, n):
    value = randint(0, size)
    check = value_exists(value, arrayA)
    if check:
        break

if check:
    print(check)
```

This solution works, however it's extremely slow. For size set to `100,000,000` it takes about 30 seconds. For `10,000,000,000` I can't even get to the result (>5 minutes).

I can't realize what is so time-consuming about this task. I know the numbers are large, but they fit into a 64bit integer. I found out the `value_exists` function is the core of the problem, can it be improved?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using an array, why not use a dict? You can store the random numbers in the `key`, and store an index in the `value`.

Then, to check if the random number is in the collection, just use `in`.

Example:

```
import random

# Create a large list of random numbers
A_list = random.sample(xrange(100000, 999999), 10000)

# EDIT: Forgot to sort the array!
A_list = sorted(A_list)

# Load the numbers in a dictionary
A_dict = {}
for idx, num in enumerate(A_list):
    A_dict[num] = idx

# Now, check if a number exists
if 101337 in A_dict:
    # it exists!
    # Get its index
    return A_dict[101337]
```

Comment: I don't lean on array usage. By 'array' I ment the general meaning of array. I'll look into this solution in a second

Comment: @thefourtheye If you noticed, I DID generate a large array of random numbers. I just loaded them into a dict for easier searching. My solution still returns the index of the number in the list.

Comment: @nivixzixer Even I wanted to suggest this, but then I thought OP would want to do this only with the list. Also, I would throw in a dictionary comprehension

Comment: @nivixzixer No, after sorting you lose the actual indexes. For the dictionary based solution, sorting is totally not necessary.

Comment: @thefourtheye I just tested this on my machine. Generating the random number list, sorting it, loading it into a dictionary, it all works. Nothing is lost. Maybe take this to chat?

Comment: Why OP uses enumerate in the question? To preserve the original order. When you sort it you lose original order. I think the point of the question is to teach about searching a sorted list. Ah.. I see it now.

Comment: Ahh.. so he wants to find the index of a number from the original list? Before the sort? Didn't catch that, sorry.

Comment: Actually its not clear what OP wants. For practical purposes even I would use dictionary only

Comment: @nivixzixer yes indeed. I've added an example in the original question, hope that helps. Sorry for the misunderstandings.

Comment: I think @thefourtheye's former solution is good one. I'll try it thoroughly tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

First of all as a more efficient way you can use a generator expression in `value_exists` function also you don't need to check  `item[1] > needle` :

```
def value_exists(needle, haystack):
    return next(item for item in haystack if item[1] == needle,None)
```

And you can create a random list with `random.sample`. for example :

```
>>> random.sample(range(100),10)
[87, 24, 71, 64, 86, 11, 59, 54, 20, 92]
```

Also again for the last part you can use a generator expression :

```
next(value_exists(randint(0, size), arrayA) for i in range(1, n),None)
```

And about the sorting your array if its necessary you can use `operator.itemgetter()` as your `key` that is more efficient for long lists :

```
from operator import itemgetter
arrayA = sorted(arrayA, key=itemgetter(1))
```